# How to get number of uncommitted write commands in transaction in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is what I want to do

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES ('a','b')
INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES ('c','d')
```

How can I get the number of commands in the transaction before committing? Like the number of uncommitted commands in above example is `2`

Comment: How would you count `INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES ('a','b'), ('c', 'd');` or `INSERT INTO sample_table SELECT a, b FROM x;`? What are you really try to achieve?

Comment: I just want to count the number of commands in the queue(Insert commands given after begin of the transaction).

Comment: Postgres doesn't have a "queue". Concurrent access is handled via [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). Nobody is keeping a count of the number of pending changes. If you really, *really* needed to, you might get somewhere by digging through every record in every table and comparing [`xmin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) against [`txid_current()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#idm46428705509888), but in a large database, this could take minutes or even hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with some limitation you [can use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) `cmin +1` formula. Of course you have to know all tables where you insert. Also in my demo I show how to do it with inserts only, updates and deletes will require more logic, including xmax (if possible at all), anyway, here the code to give it a try...

sample:

```
t=# create table ut1(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create table ut2(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into ut1 select generate_series(1,10);
INSERT 0 10
t=# insert into ut2 select generate_series(1,10);
INSERT 0 10
```

demo:

```
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# insert into ut1 select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into ut2 select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into ut2 select generate_series(1,2);
INSERT 0 2
t=#  insert into ut1 select generate_series(1,2);
INSERT 0 2
t=# select greatest(max(ut1.cmin::text::int),max(ut2.cmin::text::int)) from ut2 join ut1 on ut1.xmin = ut2.xmin and (ut1.xmin)::text::bigint = txid_current();
 greatest
----------
        3
(1 row)

t=# end;
COMMIT
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# insert into ut1 select generate_series(1,2);
INSERT 0 2
t=# insert into ut2 select generate_series(1,2);
INSERT 0 2
t=# select greatest(max(ut1.cmin::text::int),max(ut2.cmin::text::int)) from ut2 join ut1 on ut1.xmin = ut2.xmin and (ut1.xmin)::text::bigint = txid_current();
 greatest
----------
        1
(1 row)

t=# end;
COMMIT
```